# will the list ensure the order while the data is served from service to app?

Tags: rest, api, service, pagination, client

Building an pagination API. Assume the request is coming for 0 to 5 resources.

The API returns the 5 resources in an order.

But there is no explicit sequence number or order in the responses.

When the data is transferred in a network, will the list ensures the order while the data is served from service to app?

My worries are Service will be in some technology stack - java/node-js etc., The client can be java based android app, js based react native app, another backend service in java/node-js.

Each one will have own serialization and deserialization libraries. Will it be consistent in order the elements.

I am thinking of adding explicit sequence number/index values, explicitly tell the clients to use sequence number/index values for any ordering/sorting based operations.

Is my understanding correct?
Does explicit sequence number needed or not?
Does the serialization and de-serialization library maintains the order?

Comment: Why don't you sort the response in the consumer to be sure?

Comment: Yes, we can do that. But would like to understand more about whether the ordering can persisted in wire?

Answer (score 0):

to be sure to get the order you want, you could achieve it in one line if sort text object:

```
arrayResults.sort((a, b)=> b.titleObject.toUpperCase().localeCompare(a.titleObject.toUpperCase()))
```

sort number:

```
arrayResults.sort((a, b)=> b.numberObject - a.numberObject)
```

Then you could paginate peacefully